# PDF attachment in email is called 'Noname'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

When I send an email with a attached pdf file the email only shows a file called 'Noname'. The file itself is the multipart section of the email with the base64 attached pdf. How can I send the PDF so it comes up as an attachment and doesn't corrupt the email?

Here is my code:

```
attachments['126539_statistics.pdf'] = File.read("app/assets/pdfs/126539_statistics.pdf")
mail(:to => email, :subject => subject, :body => message,  :content_type => 'application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had face same problem. I have corrected it by following way

1) As per ActionMailer Guide, You need to make view file into app/views/[action_mailer_model_name]/[method_name]

Here is reference of guide: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

2) Action Mailer is smart enough that it identify content-type automatically while reading file. So there is no need to pass explicitly 'application/pdf' in your mail function.

Hope, this information helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 4):

Also experienced the same problem 
solution is :
 set Attachments before sending mail function.

code is attached below:

```
 attachments["invoice_#{invoice.bill_date.strftime('%B-%Y')}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string  pdf: 'project_report.pdf',
                          template: 'users/_invoice.html.erb'
    )
    mail(to: email , from: from, subject: subject) do |format|
          format.html
      end
```