# Rails 5.0.1 - ActionMailer with MailGun, setting 'noname' for filename when directly attaching base64 string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have read the entire official guide [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) and about 5 questions on SO that describe this problem for Rails 3 and Rails 4.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022417/rails-4-5-sending-dynamic-actionmailerbase-mail-email-with-attachment-labeled) is for Rails 5, but he is using an actual file, not an encoded string.

This is my mailer code (and yes I have both views setup). The email comes through perfectly fine, with the attached PDF.

```
  def pdf_quote(proposal)
    @proposal = proposal
    email_with_name = %("#{@proposal.first_name} #{@proposal.last_name}" <#{@proposal.email}>)
    filename = "QD-#{@proposal.qd_number}_#{@proposal.last_name}.pdf"
    attachments[filename] = {
      mime_type: 'application/pdf',
      encoding: 'Base64',
      content: @proposal.pdf_base64
    }  
    mail(
      to: email_with_name,
      from: 'Floorbook UK <email address>',
      subject: 'Your Personal Flooring Quote is attached',
      sent_on: Time.now
      )    
  end
```

In gmail the attachment is called 'noname' and in Postbox it is called 'pb_mime_attachment.pdf'

How can I get ActionMailer to use the filename I provide?

Note that I am using MailGun (mailgun-ruby gem 1.1.4) to send the email, so it could be the gem at fault here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug with 3rd party mailgun-ruby gem.

I raised a bug with them, here are the details:
https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/issues/82

It is fixed (I tested it) in version 1.1.5.